# I have an array of urls which i used to fetch videos and store it in an array

Tags: jquery

But as the GET method is asynchronous,before getting the content it starts operating.How to make it synchronous

```
var $arr4=[];
for(var i=1;i<$arr3.length;i++)
{
   url_new=url.split("_")[0];
   url_new=url_new+"/"+$arr3[i];
   $.get( url_new, function( data ) { 
      $arr4.push(data); 

 myFunction(url,$arr4);
```

Comment: Can you post full code?

Answer (score 0):

```
var $arr4=[];
function getData(arr,i){
url_new=url.split("_")[0];
url_new=url_new+"/"+arr[i];
    $.get( url_new, function( data ) { 
       $arr4.push(data);
       i++;
   if(i < arr.length){
   getData(arr,i)
           }
   }
 }

  getData(arr3,0)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!